# Ghost image missing during drag and drop

Tags: javascript, css

Javascript noob...

My partner is a kindergarten teacher and sometime asks me to make things she can use in her classroom. She asked me to make a "Function Machine". I've made it and it is working fine. I cobbled together some JS to make it work with a drag and drop. 
The problem I am having is when dragging, the ghost image of what is being dragged is lost. I think the issue is what I am grabbing with the JS on drag. I am grabbing the info from data attributes.

Can anyone think of a way to get a ghost image to appear?

Codepen: [Function Machine](https://codepen.io/west4me/pen/jxxVBW)

HTML

```
    <html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Function Machine</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-G0fIWCsCzJIMAVNQPfjH08cyYaUtMwjJwqiRKxxE/rx96Uroj1BtIQ6MLJuheaO9" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper" class="toggled">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="text-center">
        <span class="choose">Select Operator:</span>
        <div class="row mt-2">
          <div class="col-5 ml-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block addBut"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block subBut"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="sidebar-nav choice add">

        <li class="instruct my-2">Drag the rule to the rule box</li>
        <li draggable="true">
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="add1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="add" data-value="1">
            Add 1
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="add2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="add" data-value="2">
            Add 2
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="add3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="add" data-value="3">
            Add 3
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="add4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="add" data-value="4">
            Add 4
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="add5" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="add" data-value="5">
            Add 5
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="add6" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="add" data-value="6">
            Add 6
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="add7" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="add" data-value="7">
            Add 7
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="add8" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="add" data-value="8">
            Add 8
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="add9" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="add" data-value="9">
            Add 9
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="add10" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="add" data-value="10">
            Add 10
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!-- SUBTRACTION -->
      <ul class="sidebar-nav choice sub">
        <li class="instruct">Drag the rule to the rule box</li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="sub1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="subtract" data-value="1">
            Subtract 1
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="sub2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="subtract" data-value="2">
            Subtract 2
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="sub3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="subtract" data-value="3">
            Subtract 3
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="sub4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="subtract" data-value="4">
            Subtract 4
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="sub5" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="subtract" data-value="5">
            Subtract 5
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="sub6" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="subtract" data-value="6">
            Subtract 6
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="sub7" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="subtract" data-value="7">
            Subtract 7
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="sub8" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="subtract" data-value="8">
            Subtract 8
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="sub9" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="subtract" data-value="9">
            Subtract 9
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="dragger"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
          <div id="sub10" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="number" data-operation="subtract" data-value="10">
            Subtract 10
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="wrap">
          <h1 id="logo">Function Machine</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="machine">
          <div class="machineHolder">
            <input id="numberIn" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Number">
            <i class="arrowdown fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
            <svg id="funcMachine" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 127 113.98"><defs><style>.cls-1,.cls-4{fill:#88C542;}.cls-1,.cls-3{stroke:#333;stroke-miterlimit:10;}.cls-2{font-size:25px;fill:#333;font-family:OpenSans-Bold, Open Sans;font-weight:700;}.cls-3{fill:none;}</style></defs><title>functionMachine</title><path id="mainBox" class="cls-1" d="M14.38,17.5H126.5a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V82.63A13.88,13.88,0,0,1,112.63,96.5H.5a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V31.38A13.88,13.88,0,0,1,14.38,17.5Z"/><path id="in" class="cls-1" d="M21.94,18.06,12.5,8.63V.5h29V8.75L32.15,18.1S21.93,18.07,21.94,18.06Z"/><path id="out" class="cls-1" d="M105.15,95.92l9.43,9.44v8.12h-29v-8.25l9.35-9.35S105.16,95.91,105.15,95.92Z"/>
                        <path id="RuleBox" class="cls-1" d="M126.5,82.63V57H.5V96.5H112.63A13.87,13.87,0,0,0,126.5,82.63Z"/><text class="cls-2" transform="translate(11.95 46)">Rule</text><line class="cls-3" x1="0.5" y1="57.02" x2="126.5" y2="57.02"/><rect id="coverup" class="cls-4" x="20.96" y="18.05" width="12.21" height="2.83"/><rect id="coverup-2" data-name="coverup" class="cls-4" x="22.17" y="16.46" width="9.83" height="6.21"/><rect id="coverup-3" data-name="coverup" class="cls-4" x="94.4" y="93.14" width="12.21" height="2.83"/><rect id="coverup-4" data-name="coverup" class="cls-4" x="94.5" y="91.55" width="10.94" height="6.21" transform="translate(199.94 189.3) rotate(180)"/></svg>

            <div id="ruleDrop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>

            <i class="arrowup fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
            <div id="result">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-secondary" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="calcResult">Run Machine</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- /#wrapper -->


  <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
  <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #f0a32f;
}

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #844d9e;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 133px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
.add {
  display: block;
}
.sub {
  display: none;
}

.choose {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 32px;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.instruct {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}
.machine {
  width: 100%;
}
.machineHolder {
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.arrowup {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
.arrowdown {
  margin-left: 31px;
  font-size: 48px;
}

#funcMachine {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

#ruleDrop {
  width: 250px;
  height: 79px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -115px;
  font-size: 41px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

#RuleBox {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.number {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(65, 38, 78, 0.3);
}
li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(65, 38, 78, 0.3);
}

.number:hover {
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}

#result {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

/*#ruleDrop > .number {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 41px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}*/

.dragger {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.btn-info {
  background-color: #88c542;
  border-color: #88c542;
}

.btn-info:hover {
  background-color: #517627;
  border-color: #446221;
}

.titleBox {
  width: 100%;
}
.titleBox h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS

```
var currentOperation = null;

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  var elData = $(ev.target).data();
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("operation", elData.operation);
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("value", elData.value);
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.innerHTML);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.target.style.opacity = "1";
  ev.target.innerHTML = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  currentOperation = {};
  currentOperation.operation = ev.dataTransfer.getData("operation");
  currentOperation.value = ev.dataTransfer.getData("value");
}


$("#calcResult").click(function() {
  var inputNum = $("#numberIn").val();
  inputNum = parseInt(inputNum);
  var result = 0;

  if (currentOperation) {
    var value = parseInt(currentOperation.value);
    if (currentOperation.operation == "subtract") {
      result = inputNum - value;
    } else if (currentOperation.operation == "add") {
      result = inputNum + value;
    }
  }
  //Display result
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;

  $(".arrowdown").addClass("animated bounce");
});

$(".addBut").click(function() {
  $(".add").css("display", "block");
  $(".sub").css("display", "none");
});

$(".subBut").click(function() {
  $(".add").css("display", "none");
  $(".sub").css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: What browser are you using? In chrome I see a hint of the element, but not the entirety.

Comment: I'm using chrome as well. When I drag all I see is the cursor change to the not allowed cursor.

Comment: Are you on Windows 10, Mac OS? (I'm trying to pinpoint why we are seeing differences)

Comment: Sorry, Windows 7
Chrome 66.... No ghost image
IE 11 White rectangle for ghost image
Firefox 59 seeing somewhat of a ghost image.

Since this is for a very specific use for one person, I'm only worried about chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out.

```
var crt = ev.target.cloneNode(true);
    crt.style.backgroundColor = "purple";

    crt.style.transform = "translateX(-5000px)"; /* or visibility: hidden, or any of the above */
    document.body.appendChild(crt);
    ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(crt, 0, 0);
```